# What are the use-cases when we should prefer a broadcast receiver, AIDL, Ibinder?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, aidl

I want to know the use-cases when an AIDL is better option than broadcast receiver and vice-versa.Similarly, a use-case when Ibinder is better than broadcast receiver and AIDL

Answer (score 11):

## BroadcastReceiver

1. Type of communicating entities: Mostly different apps.
2. Communication is triggered by : Sender
3. Communication is received by : Any number of receivers (One to Many)
4. Does sender know who is receiving ? : Mostly No.
5. Real World Analogy: You write something on a paper and display it on
   a public notice board. Whoever interested reads.

*Example:*
You are writing an app that will log the call times every-time user receives a call. You app will respond to the broadcasts for the PHONE_STATE

## AIDL

1. Type of communicating entities: Different apps.
2. Communication is triggered by : Receiver
3. Communication is received by : Receiver only. (One to One)
4. Does sender know who is receiving ? : Yes
5. Real World Analogy: You receive a letter with return postage. You use the same envelope and postage to write a reply to the sender.

*Example:*
Your app has asked user to buy some in-app product and you need to call Play Service's to check if the user has successfully processed the payment and purchased the in app items.

## Bound Services within app

1. Type of communicating entities: Mostly components in the same app.
2. Communication is triggered by : Receiver
3. Communication is received by : Receiver only. (One to One)
4. Does sender know who is receiving ? : Yes.
5. Real World Analogy: You are sitting in a classroom, a friend passes you a chit, you write a reply on it and give it back to him.

*Example:*
You app has 5 screens and each screen has a button which takes screenshot and saves it to filesystem. You can decouple the take screenshot/save to file logic in a service and all screen simply call the service.

**NOTE:** In case of AIDL based IPC you need to use Bound service to call the remote process.